# How can I draw the pipes A and B filling water tank as shown below in latex?

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]I'm getting difficult to draw pipes and cisterns, please help me out I'm stack here

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
    
    % draw tank
    \draw (0,0) -- (6,0) -- (6,4) -- (0,4) -- cycle;
    
    % draw water level
    \fill [blue!50] (0,0.5) -- (6,0.5) -- (6,2.5) -- (0,2.5) -- cycle;
    
    % draw pipe
    \draw [thick] (6.5,0.8) -- (7.5,0.8) -- (7.5,3.2) -- (6.5,3.2);
    
    % draw labels
    \node [below] at (3,0) {(a)};
    \node [below] at (9,0) {(b)};
    \node [below] at (15,0) {(c)};
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Pipe filling a tank}
    \label{fig:pipe-tank}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hoe the image should look? A sketch would be helpful ...